# how to capture image metadata in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, nodes, node-modules

I have a google image and from that want to pull longitude,latitude and location information.I may get the image through google maps url which is referring to image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Angular's [meta-service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) may be of assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't provide such a service.

However you can install one of the many npm packages that can help you there. For example:
[exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js)